# awesome wm: set a hotkey to open mutt

Tags: hotkeys, mutt, awesome-wm

I'm using awesome 3.4 on debian jessie. I'd like to add the hotkey combo mod + m to open mutt.

I had thought that `awful.key({ modkey,           }, "m", function () awful.util.spawn_with_shell("mutt") end),` would work, but it does not.

How would I setup this hotkey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly spawn a terminal window if you want to use a terminal program.  The "with_shell" in `awful.util.spawn_with_shell()` does not mean that it does this, but the difference to `awful.util.spawn()` is that the former calls `sh -c <program>` and the latter just calls `<program>` (i.e. `spawn_with_shell()` does shell expansion, `spawn()` doesn't).

The following should do the trick:

```
awful.key({ modkey, }, "m", function () awful.util.spawn("xterm -e mutt") end)
```

Note that most™ `awesome`-configs (e.g. the default one shipped with `awesome`) define a variable `terminal`, thus you could (and probably should) also use:

```
[…] awful.util.spawn(terminal .. " -e mutt") […]
```

In this way you only have to change the definition of `terminal` in case you want to change from e.g. `xterm` to `urxvt` (something I could really advice ;)

Comment: Thanks... not sure how I didn't think of just opening a shell.